# Pick up errors from multiple columns in a row in SSIS Data Conversion error output

Tags: ssis, etl

I wish to capture data conversion errors using the error output of a data conversion transform and send them to a row count.

The issue is, if there is an error in multiple columns in the same row, I only get the error column number for the first error it finds. Then I fix that error, run the package again, and find there is a second error on that row.

I want a way to find every data conversion error that exists in the input all at once, so I can avoid unnecessary reruns of the package.

[image: screenshot of data flow layout - data conversion transform error output leads to row count]

UPDATE: Below is an example.
The "Date" column encounters an error on data conversion, because the value is not type Date [DT_Date]. But "ServiceDeliveryLocationPostcode" should be type Numeric [DT_Numeric], but the value show is not numeric, so it is also an error. The data viewer only shows an error in column 43 (which is the "Date" column), but the row has 2 errors on it. I want to know if there is a way to structure my data flow so that I can capture all the errors that occur on a row, not just the first error from left to right.

[image: Screenshot of data viewer showing error column and error code]

Comment: Can you please share an example ? Input and expected output ?

Comment: @AmiraBedhiafi I have now added an example